# European tour - advice wanted

Tags: visas, international-travel

I'm looking to take a 3 week trip to Europe next year in the spring. Ideally, I'd like to know only the city in which I'll land and the AirBnB I'll stay in for the first couple nights, and then just wing it after that.

As far as I know, a Schengen Visa requires you to state which city you're going to be in the longest, and then you obtain your visa from that country's embassy. Is this true?

Is AirBnB prolific (and still legal) in most of Europe? I'm planning to hit the UK (England/Ireland), France, Italy, Netherlands, Germany, Czech Republic, and maybe Scandinavia. I stayed in an AirBnB last year in Berlin but it was seen as quite risky for my host as the city had banned it.

Any other advice for travelling around and between countries would be greatly appreciated too :)

Comment: Could be useful to split this in two questions: AirBnB and visa.

Comment: "Any other advice..."  you will need a lot of money  :/

Comment: @Fattie how far will about 3000 EUR get me?

Comment: UK has its own visa process separate from the Schengen zone, as does Republic of Ireland which is not part of the UK

Comment: 30 nites - 100 euros a nite - that's tough man.  have you considered, just go to ONE city (say, Zurich or Milano, or just Paris) and just STAY PUT in that one city.  find a holiday rental in the central area for the whole three weeks.  you will get all european and cool feeling!  travelling around is tedious  :/

Comment: @Fattie I did consider it, but I'd rather travel to a few different cities and have the experience :)

Comment: Side note, Berlin has a problem with people who turn residential apartments into de-facto hotels without the necessary planning permits (which may be impossible to get for those apartments). The crackdown on these "professional AirBnB hosts" might hit "occasional AirBnB hosts" as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your profile, I presume that you are a South African citizen and need a visa. Schengen and non-Schengen visa are different procedures.

- You are supposed to get a Schengen visa from the *country* which is your main destination, or if there is no clear main destination, from the country which is the first destination of your trip. So you could apply for a visa from your first planned destination in the Schengen zone.
- The visa officials will try to admit genuine tourists and refuse illegal immigrants. Part of the criteria is a coherent premise and itinerary of the trip. So if your premise is *spend 100 € a day, let's see where you go,* that would be quite unusual but not impossible. The rest of your application would have to be very strong, with clear indications that the money is **really** yours and that you **really** will leave after the holiday.